# Java 11 : Create class instance out of generic type

Tags: java

I'd like to implement a custom deserialization object in Java 11. For this I have

```
public class ObjectDeserializer<T extends ObjectDeserializable> {
    public T deserialize(ByteBuffer buf)
    {
        T ret = instantiateNew();
        return (T) ret.deserialize(buf);
    }
}
```

How can I implement `instantiateNew()` method?
Is it possible to create an instance of class using it's type ? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Using reflection: You can obtain a reference to the class of `T`. With `Class<T>` you can access the no argument constructor (provided the class has one) using `getConstructor()`. Finally you can call `newInstance()` to create a new instance.

Comment: Since generic types are erased at runtime, you need a reference to the class. Some mapping frameworks prefer it as an argument to the method, like `<T> T deserialize(ByteBuffer, Class<T>)`